# Generating a n-dimensional random vector parameterized by a k dimensional random vector

Tags: python-2.7, probability, sampling, probability-theory

I have a n-dimensional random vector.  I need to generate a k-dimensional random vector which is based on this n-dimensional random vector (paramterized).  Is there any probability distribution which is parameterized in the above way ?

I also want the k-dimensional random vector to be positive and preferable between 0 and 1.  How can I do this in python ?

Comment: This seems pretty broad as stated. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I want to generate some synthetic datasets such that dataset features are related to dataset metadata. dataset feature is k dimensional and metadata is m dmensional.  The simple approach I am thinking is, sample a dimensional vector from uniform distribution and give that as hyperparameter of a distrbution which returns a fixed size (m or k) random vector.

Comment: One special case would be to start with a R^m random metadata vector, pass it through a complicated function from R^m to R, and generate IID observations from some distribution with a scalar parameter. You can generate a bunch of complicated functions dynamically by randomly composing things like `np.sin, np.exp` etc. You can then meet the normalization requirement by normalizing after the fact.

Comment: Or you could make an m times k matrix by sampling the metadata observation, and get features by multiplying uniform k-vectors by the above matrix. This will probably be unexciting if k is large.

Comment: metadata is also artificial. It is not observed. I want both the metadata and feature vectors to be related.  I did not get the approaches you advised.  My idea is to start from a uniform random n dimensional vector to generate k and m dimensional vectors from it. But I dont know a good way to generate the k and m vectors from a n vector

Comment: You can view generating metadata as a special case of your problem with m=k. For example, start with `np.random.rand(m)` generate "features" that will end up being used as metadata. This is why I assume that metadata is given. Above that, there is a huge list of things you could do that fits the above description, so I cannot make an informed recommendation without more specific requirements.

Comment: @Shew Do I understand correctly that you want to create an artificial data set for a classifier with n inputs and k outputs?